# FirebaseUser returning null email even when FirebaseUser is not null

Tags: android

The String email returns as null even when currentUser is not null. User has email as the identifier in Firebase console.

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if (currentUser == null) {
        sendToLogin();
    } else {
        this.email = currentUser.getEmail();
    }
}
```

I expect the output to be example@gmail.com, but the actual output is null

Comment: did you try debugging or printing currentUser variable once you ot ir form mAuth??

Comment: If there is no initialization of `mAuth` in `onStart` where have initialized it ? `onStart` is the very first method called in an activity . Probably the app would crash..

Comment: May be possible @Santanu

Comment: Try to code in `onCreate()` instead of `onStart()`

Comment: I think you initialize `mAuth` in `onCreate()` method!

Comment: @DineshShingadiya yes it stopped returning null when i moved the code to onCreate() ! thank you